# How to convert decimal scientific notation float/double to normal string

Tags: c++, floating-point, scientific-notation

I know there are many questions solving this problem when the number is not very large, but when it comes to large numbers (while still in range of float/double), the output will lose precision :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    double d = -1e307, d2 = 1e307;
    std::cout << std::fixed << d << std::endl;

    printf("d2 is %lf\n", d2);
    return 0;
}
```

This code will get output like this:

```
-9999999999999999860310597602564577717002641838126363875249660735883565852672743849064846414228960666786379280392654615393353172850252103336275952370615397010730691664689375178569039851073146339641623266071126720011020169553304018596457812688561947201171488461172921822139066929851282122002676667750021070848.000000

d2 is 9999999999999999860310597602564577717002641838126363875249660735883565852672743849064846414228960666786379280392654615393353172850252103336275952370615397010730691664689375178569039851073146339641623266071126720011020169553304018596457812688561947201171488461172921822139066929851282122002676667750021070848.000000
```

But this is obviously not correct! How to make real conversion?!

Comment: Floating point numbers are not precise. There is no way around it other than not using floating point.

Comment: `std::cout << d` does not "lose precision". The compile time conversion of `"-1e307"` to `double` lost the precision.

Comment: Numbers do not have formats. Formats apply only when you try to generate a string from a number. If you get an unexpected result, it's because the numbers can't be expressed as floating points accurately

Comment: You should create your own class to store decimal scientific notation to archieve this.

Comment: "this is obviously not correct!": contrary to your thinking, this is quite correct as it is compatible with the accuracy provided by double-precision floating point. Exact representation of the integer 1e307 would require at least 1020 bit numbers, which aren't supported natively (they are of little use for daily applications).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I handled this my self, here is my code, the function translates arbitrary float string to a normal one.

This function inspired by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90565/converting-a-double-to-a-stdstring-without-scientific-notation).

```
// DW: remove e
std::string trim_real(std::string str) {
    // DW: all to lowercase
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);

    // DW: find "e" and "."
    size_t pe = str.find_first_of("e");
    std::string se = str.substr(pe + 1, str.size() - (pe + 1));
    int de = std::stoi(se);

    // DW: get string without "e"
    std::string sc = str.substr(0, pe);
    std::cout << "sc is " << sc << std::endl;

    // DW: remove uneccessary 0
    size_t pf0 = sc.find_first_not_of("0");
    size_t pl0 = sc.find_last_not_of("0");
    std::string sc_trim = sc.substr(pf0, pl0 - pf0 + 1);
    std::cout << "sc_trim is " << sc_trim << std::endl;

    // DW: move "." according to e
    size_t pp = sc_trim.find_first_of(".");
    if (pp == std::string::npos) {
        // DW: this means there is no "."
        pp = 0;
    }
    int pp_tobe = pp + de;

    sc_trim.erase(pp, 1);
    if (de > 0) {
        // DW: should move "." to the right
        if (pp_tobe < sc_trim.size()) {
            sc_trim.insert(pp_tobe, ".");
        } else {
            sc_trim += std::string(pp_tobe - sc_trim.size() + 1, '0');
            sc_trim += ".0";
        }
    } else {
        // DW: should move "." to the left
        if (pp_tobe >= 0) {
            sc_trim.insert(pp_tobe, ".");
        } else {
            sc_trim = "." + std::string(0 - pp_tobe, '0') + sc_trim;
        }
    }

    if (sc_trim == ".") {
        // DW: this means sc_trim is actually 0 now
        sc_trim = "0.0";
    }
    return sc_trim;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that double precision floating point numbers are represented with [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) binary format using 64 bits, which have a precision of about 16 decimal digit. So the integer value that you see is the integer representable in IEE-754 format that is closest to `1e307` (resp. `-1e307`).

If you know that you want another representation, you will have to build it yourself *by hand*. The simplest way (IMHO) would be to output it on a `stringstream` with default format, and then parse it:

- if there is a `e` inside, exponent is after, and before is the mantissa in format 1.234... that is one single digit before the decimal point, just move the decimal point according to exponent, adding as many 0 as needed in front of the number (negative exponent) or after it (positive one)
- if there is no `e` inside, output is already is fixed format

Alternatively, you could try to find a *big decimal library* that would internally use an exact representation for decimal numbers (or write your own if you do not find any meeting your requirements).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after some deeper google I found a solution and improved it, you can check my improved solution and original one below :-)